# Adding background workers to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, worker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm playing around with Elastic Beanstalk and I'm trying to figure out how I might add background-workers to my application.

Is there an easy way to launch an EC2 instance with the code that's on my elastic beanstalk application servers? And have the deploy mechanism that comes with Elastic beanstalk update these instances?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am sorry I really have no idea about workers

But You can use AMAZON SDK and build an application to launch an ec2 instance based on regions and also you can specify AMI too , so there are various api calls from which you could get available regions , and also you can decide or building your own AMI with the required specification  .

Comment: with the AWS SDK can I create 'copies' of my application servers on Elastic Beanstalk and through the command line trigger certain urls/paths to get a script that's part of my application to run as a worker?

Comment: Yes I think , I have tried some api calls from amazon SDK for php only I don't know about other flavors of  SDK here is the link for documentation  [AMAZON SDK FOR ELASTIC BEAN](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#i=AmazonElasticBeanstalk) .

Comment: Take a look at such [shell-script here](http://www.metallic-badger.com/wordpress/simple-beginner-ec2-auto-start-bash-script/) and you can also use configuration software which makes your life easier.

Comment: -1 I cannot believe "I'm sorry I have no idea" is worth three votes, an accepted answer, and a bounty.

Comment: @ErickRobertson can you tell me what is wrong in my Answer , The user here just wanted to know whether automation of creating ec2 instances in Amazon cloud is possible or not if so how . My post explains that

Comment: 2014: Now, there is a dedicated environment type in AWS for this purpose called [worker tiers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html#concepts.concepts.architecture.worker).